# Run a program taking parameters after installation

Tags: command-line, windows-services, wix

I have a Windows Service and I've created an installer for the service in the same project.
Now I want to deploy my service. So I've added a new project in my solution (Wix Setup Project).

What I want now is to run my program i.e. my Windows service after installation and send a parameter so that service installs. For example the command line shuld be like this:
*MyService.exe /I*

And also a want to send a parameter */U* to uninstall my service.

Thanks

Comment: You should use ServiceInstall element: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/serviceinstall.html. It contains the attributes to pass the arguments to the installed service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this on my own.

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="InstallWinService" Before="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
  <Custom Action="UninstallWinService" Before="RemoveFiles">Installed AND NOT REINSTALL</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: Not all parts of code has been presented above. This is missing: <CustomAction Id="InstallWinService" FileKey="FILE_WinService" ExeCommand="/I" Return="check" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no"/>
    <CustomAction Id="UninstallWinService" FileKey="FILE_WinService" ExeCommand="/U" Return="check" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no"/>